# JSON Path query possibilities

Tags: json, jsonpath

What are possibility of `JSONPath queries` . Following are the queries I found from  [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)

```
$.store.book[*].author
$..author
$.store.*
$.store..price
$..book[2]
$..book[(@.length-1)]
$..book[-1:]
$..book[0,1]
$..book[:2]
$..book[?(@.isbn)]
$..book[?(@.price<10)]
$..*
```

Are following also possible queries valid in term of `JSONPath`

```
$.data2.passes[0].id
$.store.bicycle.['dot.notation']
$.['store'].bicycle.['dot.notation']
$['store']['bicycle']['dot.notation']
$.['store']['bicycle']['dot.notation']
$.['store'].['bicycle'].['dot.notation']   
$.['store'].bicycle.['dash-notation']
$['store']['bicycle']['dash-notation']
$.['store']['bicycle']['dash-notation']
$.['store'].['bicycle'].['dash-notation']    
$.store.bicycle.foo:bar"
$['store']['bicycle']['foo:bar']
$.store
$.store.book[1]    
$.store.book[*]    
$.store.book[0,1]    
$.store.book[0,1].author
$.store.book[*].author    
$.['store'].['book'][*].['author']
$['store']['book'][*]['author']
$['store'].book[*]['author']    
$..author    
$.store.*    
$.[0].[0].author    
$.[0][0].author    
$.store..['display-price']
```

When I try those queries with online evaluator [JSONPath Online Evaluator](http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator/) these do not work, So I was wondering what is correct set of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

JSONPath is not a standardised query language (nor fully implemented) - XPath is.

Using DefiantJS (http:/defiantjs.com/) you can query JSON structure with XPath expressions. To see it in action, check out the live XPath Evaluator:

http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator